# Retrieving large data issue from MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I'm having problem while retrieving huge data (8523 records) from MongoDB Collection,when i execute following line in php (using YiiMongoDBSuite)

```
 $mongocol = $mongo->$dbname->$colname->find(array('crm_base_contact_id' => array('$in' => array($base))));
 $mongotemp = iterator_to_array($mongocol,false);
```

im getting empty page,but when i execute the same code using limit(6800),im getting data in grid. but if i increase the limit to 7000 or more i'm getting empty page !!!

Note : i'm using lamp server , mongoDB version - 2.4.6

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably run out of php memory. Did you check that?

Comment: Take a look in your phps error.log. Always look into this file if you get a simple white page with nothing. That usually means out of memory error or max execution time exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on how many records a `find` statement can return. You have to make multiple queries (by `count` the rows and then loop with `limit` and `skip` specified), if you want data larger than limit.